# GeoDjango within a NE, SW box

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango

I'm creating a geo app with Google Maps and I receive bounding box as 2 coordinates:

- north east
- south west

I have a model with PointField.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    location        = models.PointField()
```

How could I perform a query to get all places within bounding box?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that the "2 coordinates" are x,y tuples, for example:

```
ne = (50.0, -90)
sw = (45.5, -95)
```

You can extract the coordinates and create a bounding box tuple:

```
xmin = sw[0]
ymin = ne[1]
xmax = sw[1]
ymax = ne[0]
bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
```

Using the bounding box geometry, query your Place records using a [spatial lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#spatial-lookups):

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)
queryset = Place.objects.filter(poly__contained=geom)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but shouldn't xmin and ymin be from the same tuple? (same with xmax/ymax)

Comment: Shouldn't be the [`contained` spatial lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#contained)?

Comment: Agree with borges. "objects.filter(poly__contained)" is the correct lookup to find all objects with the poly field within the bounding box.  Otherwise this answer got me 90% there!

Comment: Isn't it `location__contained`?

Comment: in case of points of type geography you have to use "location__coveredby"

Answer (score 25):

@Tyler's answer is wrong in many ways. The correct code would be:

```
ne = (latitude, longitude)
sw = (latitude, longitude)

xmin=sw[1]
ymin=sw[0]
xmax=ne[1]
ymax=ne[0]
bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon
geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)
queryset = Place.objects.filter(poly__contained=geom)
```

Comment: Correct. You're right. Man, can you please look at my question? It's about the case when the polygon boundaries intersect the date change line (also known as anti meridian) — https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278021/how-to-get-points-within-boundaries-which-overlaps-the-anti-meridian

Comment: I know right?  Tyler's answer left me so confused because I the sw[0] and other points were all messed up!