# How to filter points in range with geodjango

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

How do I get all locations in a given area if I have max-min lng and lat like below.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ......
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now how do I filter all locations with given min_lat,max_lat and min_lng, max_lng like this

views

```
Location.objects.filter(point__in=())
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but search either "envelope" and/or "bounding box", and you might see some techniques

Comment: @MikeT Can you please take a look at my [trouble with GeoDjango](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507033/how-to-access-a-geometry-point-field-in-postgis-database-from-django)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got help from this question [GeoDjango within a NE, SW box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466043/geodjango-within-a-ne-sw-box)
and finally solved it like this

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

bbox = (-6.9145,53.5958,-5.6085,53.1023)#min_lat,max_lat,min_lng,max_lng 
geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

Location.objects.filter(point__within=geom)
```

Comment: I believe your comments in this code snippet are wrong - I believe the arguments to from_bbox would be (min_lat, min_long, max_lat, max_long.) Although in your case you have min_long > max_long, and I don't believe this matters, as it describes the same bounding box.